# How to open a 7/8" bolt/nut?

Tags: toyota, bolts, highlander, nut, wrench

I am trying to open a 7/8" bolt/nut from a car strut but it didn't work with my midsize(about 12" long) Dewalt breaker barand I was affraid it would break with more pressure. I tried to find another breaker bar with longer hand in the Amazon but couldn't find one. May someone help me what to search to find a proper tool?

Comment: Do you mean your Dewalt was not strong enough to undo the bolt?

Comment: Can you use a socket?  That coupled with a long breaker bar or an impact would likely do the job.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian: Yes my Dewalt breaker bar was about 12" and couldn't do the job.

Comment: I found that I must search for the "Breaker bar" not "Gearwrench". I think I will buy this and hope it will solve my problem: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07WCKBK7L/ref=redir_mobile_desktop?_encoding=UTF8&aaxitk=91a8d859a5fc94241c52d72b27681b86&hsa_cr_id=3900189300901&pd_rd_plhdr=t&pd_rd_r=6bf43ac6-59ab-4827-b307-4f8e7b8aa4ac&pd_rd_w=XUY6D&pd_rd_wg=UIBJa&ref_=sbx_be_s_sparkle_mcd_asin_0_img

Comment: Rather get the 3/4 + 1/2 drive

Comment: Snap On do a breaker bar that is available in 24 or 30 inches. I have a speed wrench with knuckle end again by Snap On that is 18” in length and I have undone all the nuts needed with that - either they came undone or sheared off… But I have lost some of my power - 21 was a long time ago. Often easier to shear a seized bolt off and replace than spend 2 days farting around with de-rusting fluids…

Comment: Why don't you simply get a long iron rod? Even a used water pipe can help if it is long enough.

Comment: I've never heard of a breaker bar that's just 12" long, I suspect you are using the wrong terminology.